# How do I check a data exist or not in text file using python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Is anyone can help me to figure out this problem? I got the result 1 and 0 but I can not figure out how to write it to a file.

```
outfile = "Result.txt"
Array = ["6J", "xx", "ss", "11"]

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    with open(outfile, "w") as result:
        output_list = []
        for rec in f.read().splitlines():
            rec = rec[:-3]  
            FBlist = [rec[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(rec), 2)] 
            output_list.append(FBlist)
            print(output_list)

FBlist_set = set(FBlist)
Array_set = set (Array)

if Array_set & FBlist_set:
   print ("found")
   result.write("1")
else:
   print ("0")
   result.write("0")
```

My test.txt file is 6J7K8L.XY First, I convert that text file be like this ["6J", "7K", "8L"] . The 3 last characters is not include. Why I convert to 2 characters, because I want to compare it each 2 characters and my fixed data also 2 characters. My problem is I can not figure out how to check my fixed data with text file and return 1 or 0.

Comment: Could you please go into more detail about what the code should do when it's working correctly, and what it's doing now? While it may be easy to read your own code, intention is not always clear to others.

Comment: I updated the information @ZoeyHewll

Answer (score 1):

With the limited info you posted it would seem as though you're getting 0 always because you're comparing `Array`, an array with 4 string elements, with the first 2 elements of each `FBlist` element you appended to the `output_list` array. I could only imagine the comparison looking something like this:

```
 ["6J", "xx", "ss", "11"] == [element1, element2]
```

which will always be False. Hoaw about a sample of what's in the test.txt file?

Also: `int(True)` and `int(False)` will always give you 1 or 0 respectively so no need for `str((0,1)[found])` you can just do `str(found)`

Edit 1:

In response to your comment, make this adjustment in your code to see what it is you are comparing:

```
for line in output_list:
    print('comparing {arr} == {line} ?'.format(arr=Array, line=line[:3])
    found = int(Array == line[:3])
    result.write(found)
```

From your comment I see an immediate problem, `Array` has 4 item while item[:3] has 3 item so they will never be the same...

Comment: My test.txt file is 6J7K8L.XY
First, I convert that text file be like this ["6J", "7K", "8L"] . The 3 last characters is not include. Why I convert to 2 characters, because I want to compare it each 2 characters and my fixed data also 2 characters. My problem is I can not figure out how to check my fixed data with text file and return 1 or 0.

Comment: @Job Surely the test must be `Array[:3] == line`. The two lists must have the same length, otherwise they will never match.

Comment: @ekhumoro is essentially saying the same as me, you are comparing 2 arrays of different lengths. How about you tell us what exactly it is you are trying to achieve with this code...

Comment: I tried to use Array[:3] == line but still give me always 0. My excpectation of this code is, I can check whether my array data exist or not in text file and write the result in a new file, which is 1 or 0. @Verbal_Kint

Comment: @Job try printing both to see the output

Comment: Which one do you want to see the output? I tried to print this part :
for line in output_list:
   found = int(Array == line[:3])
   print (found)
the output is always 0. @Verbal_Kint

Comment: @Job I meant to print your `Array` and `line` variables in the loop to see exactly what it is you're comparing.

Comment: When I print Array, it return : ["6J", "xx", "ss", "11"]
When I print line, it return :  ["6J", "7K", "8L"]
@Verbal_Kint

Comment: I tried this and it return 1 and 0 . But I can not figure out to write it to a file :


@Verbal_Kint I edited my first code