# How do I write an output to a file with parameter path in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, path

I want to write an output of `FB` to a file, but I want to use parameter for the path, I dont want to use the path like this `(C:\User\Log.txt)` to write a file. I tried this way, but It still fail.

```
Param(
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$i, $k
)

$Get_Path = $k
$Get_Path
---------- #
$FB = Get-Content $i
$FBSg = $FB.Substring(0, $FB.Length-3)
$FB = $FB -split '(..)' -join '|'

$Log = $FB Out-File $Get_Path "Log.txt"
```

Comment: See my comment about learning a scripting language [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151232/batch-script-to-rename-folder-to-a-new-name-and-increment-new-name#comment97044286_55151232) and take advantage of the power of scripting.

Comment: @ZF007 Why do you think recommending python in a question tagged [tag:powershell] or [tag:batch-file] does help in any way?

Comment: @LotPings Judging on the type of questions OP is asking there seem to be a struggle on how to code/script in the "blind" from command-line. (perhaps using a text file with written code that can be copy/paste into the command-line).  See OPs remark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819452/how-do-i-check-a-data-exist-or-not-in-text-file-using-python) about getting "exit code 1 and 0" which imo indicates that. Therefor my link towards scripting editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write content to a file using this function: `Add-Content $Get_Path $FB`

This function will create a new file for you, if the file doesn't exist. When you want to make sure that the file get's resetted before writing the content, simply delete the file:
`if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($path)) { Remove-Item –path $Get_Path }`

Comment: I want to write an output of $FB to a new text file